# Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' in an image with vuetify loader

Tags: node.js, vuetify.js, vuex

I spent few hours on just trying to load a static image in my vuetify website. I have this following code in a v-toolbar:

```
<template class="d-flex align-center">
            <v-img
                :alt="appName"
                class="shrink mr-2"
                contain
                :src="require('./../static/images/logo64.jpg')"
                transition="scale-transition"
                width="40"
            />
</template>
```

And it doesn't wanna load it. I have sass, sass-loader, style-loader and vuetify-loader in my devDependencies in my package.json file, and all of my code is working fine with vuetify, vue and vuex besides that.

Here is the full error:

[image]

Did I forget to do something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a completely different jpg? Also, check if file extension is lowercase, always use .jpg instead of .JPG

**edit:**
if u can, please, post the full error message...

**edit2:**
the error is clear, you don't have a loader to process the image file.
First try to **install file-loader**, if that don't solve the problem, check your webpack.config, probably the section below is missing(or not including jpg):

```
{
  test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
  loader: 'file-loader',
  options: {
  name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
}
```

Comment: I've tried a completely different jpg and my extension is in lowercase yes, but I still have the same error.

Here is the full error message:

 https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5VLg.png

Comment: @Zarcoin answer updated :)

Comment: Thank you very much, it fixed my problem indeed ! Took a template vuetify website somewhere and they apparently didn't add those formats :/
I also had to add ".default" after my require() to make it work